# vips_realpath and vips__file_open_write: unable to form filename unix error firebase cloud_functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, sharp

I am trying to upload a base_64 image to firebase cloud functions, using sharp.
I have the following code:

```
// Create image of question
export async function drawQuestionImage(question: any): Promise<any> {
    const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200)
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

    // Write "Awesome!"
    ctx.font = '30px Impact'
    ctx.rotate(0.1)
    ctx.fillText('Awesome!', 50, 100)

    // Draw line under text
    const text = ctx.measureText('Awesome!')
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.lineTo(50, 102)
    ctx.lineTo(50 + text.width, 102)
    ctx.stroke()

    // Draw cat with lime helmet
    await loadImage(`${process.cwd()}/backgrounds/bg.jpg`).then(async (image) => {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 50, 0, 70, 70)
        //console.log('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />')
            const base64 = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");;
            if (!base64 || !question) {
              return null;
            }

       const filePath = `questions/${question.id}`;
       const filename = `${question.id}.png`;
      // Resize source image
      await sharp(Buffer.from(base64.toString(), 'base64'))
        //.resize(size, size)
        .toFile(filePath);
     // Upload to GCS
     return bucket.upload(filePath, {
        destination: join(dirname(filePath), filename)
      });

    });
}
```

After the function is triggered I keep getting the error message:

> Error: vips_realpath: unable to form filename unix error: No such file
>   or directory vips__file_open_write: unable to open file
>   "questions/zv872JxW" for writing unix error: No such file or
>   directory

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sharp won't create a temporary directory to house the file before you upload it to Cloud Storage.

`filePath` is also missing the filename/basename (**with the extension name**).

So:

```js
...
import { tmpdir } from 'os';
import { ensureDir, remove } from 'fs-extra';


export async function drawQuestionImage(question: any): Promise<any> {

    // Create a temporary directory to house files, and ensure it exists.
    const workingDir = join(tmpdir(), 'thumbs');
    await ensureDir(workingDir);

   ...
   ...
   ...

    const fileName = `${question.id}.png`,
        filePath = join(workingDir, fileName), // Tmp path for resized image
        bucketDir = `questions/${question.id}/`, // Dir in bucket
        destination = join(bucketDir, fileName); // Ultimate image name in bucket

    // Resize source image
    await sharp(Buffer.from(base64.toString(), 'base64'))
        .resize(size, size)
        .toFile(filePath);

    // Upload to GCS
    await bucket.upload(filePath, { destination });
    return remove(workingDir); // Clear up by deleting entire tmp directory.
};
```

Note the three new imports. You could also use [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) here. We create the temporary directory, and nest the resized image inside it (`filePath`). Then we call upload with the file, passing a complete path (`destination`) as the **absolute** location within the bucket. Finally we nuke the house.